# How to use gnu utils to select one line from these three lines?

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep, readelf

So basically I want to use this command to get the `.plt` section info.

```
readelf -S ELF_Binary | awk '/plt/ {print $2,$4,$5,$6} '
```

and the output is like this:

```
.rel.plt 08048b20 000b20 0001f0
.plt 08048d40 000d40 0003f0
.got.plt 08050ff4 007ff4 000104
```

So basically I only want to get the middle line, which is :

```
.plt 08048d40 000d40 0003f0
```

I tried several ways but I just cannot make it...

Could anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of matching lines containing `plt`, say that you want the second field to be `.plt`:

```
readelf -S ELF_Binary | awk '$2==".plt" {print $2,$4,$5,$6}'
```

Comment: I guess it should be `$1==".plt"`

Comment: @Jotne No.  Observe the output OP gets.